# awk to average matching strings in file

Tags: awk

I am trying to average the matching `$2` lines using the total of the values in `$3` with `awk`.  My attempts below have not yielded the desired results.  I am doing something wrong but do not know what.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr7:83016288-83016376 SEMA3E 70.3
chr7:83606437-83606522 SEMA3A 78.6
chr7:83640327-83640417 SEMA3A 79.2
chr8:61693548-61693999 CHD7 83.4
chr8:61714076-61714162 CHD7 86.5
```

**desired output** --3 decimals

```
SEMA3A 76.0
CHD7 84.9
```

**awk attempt 1**

```
awk '{cnt[$2]++ } {sum += $3 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }' input
79.6 -- average of all lines in input
```

**awk attempt 2**

```
awk '{cnt+=$2; num+=$3} END{print "avg="cnt/num}' input
avg=0 -- not sure what this is calculating
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sum[$2]+=$3; count[$2]++} 
    END{for(k in sum) printf "%s %.1f\n",  k, sum[k]/count[k]}' file

CHD7 85.0
SEMA3A 78.9
SEMA3E 70.3
```