# AWK to get average of three columns over an ID

Tags: awk

I would like to ask for help. Here's the file format:

```
contig001 10 1 10 0.0000 0.1234 0.1234
contig001 10 1 10 0.0000 0.1678 0.1987
contig001 10 1 10 0.0111 0.1211 0.1234
contig002 245 1 10 0.0000 0.1456 0.1670
contig002 245 1 10 0.1234 0.1111 0.1098
contig002 245 1 10 0.1113 0.1111 0.1099
contig002 300 1 10 0.1112 0.1871 0.1229
contig003 100 1 10 0.0000 0.1234 0.1234
```

How to I modify this code so that it will also get the mean of $4, $5, and $6 for entries with the same contig number AND position (indicated in $1 and $2 in the example format, respectively):

```
$ awk '{sum[$2]+=$3; count[$2]++} 
    END{for(k in sum) printf "%s %.1f\n",  k, sum[k]/count[k]}' file
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012455/6696551)

Also, if the number of "collapsible" entries is less than 5 (I only indicated 3 in the example input file, though), it will not compute for the average.

Here's the expected file.out (assuming the values here are the mean values already):

```
contig001 10 1 10 0.1982 0.1987 0.1223
contig002 245 1 10 0.0123 0.1324 0.1452
```

Not very relevant (?) info:
Actually, the "duplicates" were from the cat-sort-uniq command combo (however, I don't know how to remove duplicates that are less than 5) of 50 files. Originally, I would be asking about AWK-ing across multiple files to get mean for each column; however, I thought collapsing duplicates will be an easier task than reiterating through each file (esp with the 2-column ID complication).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -v mindup=3 '
  {
    i=$1 FS $2
  }

  !C[i]++ {
    for(j=3; j<=NF-4; j++)
      M[i]=M[i] FS $j
  }
  {
    for(j=1; j<=3; j++)
      A[i,j]+=$(NF-3+j)
  }

  END {
    for(i in C)
      if(C[i]>=mindup)
        print i M[i], A[i,1]/C[i], A[i,2]/C[i], A[i,3]/C[i]
  }
' file
```

`mindup` is set to 3 for the sample. Set it to 5 for your actual file.

The inputfile has lines with 6 fields and 7 fields. This approach takes this variability into account and assumes the average is for the last three fields on the line. The M array contains the fields in between the index fields and the last three fields for a given index.

### --edit--

If fact, is the remaining fields are the same for any given index, which I assume they are, then it can be simplified to:

```
awk -v mindup=3 '
  {
    i=x
    for(j=1; j<=NF-4; j++) 
      i=i $j FS
    C[i]++
    for(j=1; j<=3; j++)
      A[i,j]+=$(NF-3+j)
  }

  END {
    for(i in C)
      if(C[i]>=mindup)
        print i A[i,1]/C[i], A[i,2]/C[i], A[i,3]/C[i]
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go...

```
 awk '{k=$1 FS $2; 
       for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) s[k,i]+=$i; 
       c[k]++} 
  END {for(k in c) 
         if(c[k]>4) 
           {printf "%s", k OFS; 
            for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) 
              printf "%.1f%s", s[k,i]/c[k], (i==NF?ORS:OFS)}}' file
```

note that for the qualifier`!(n<5) == n>4`, also your expected output values are not correct, may confuse other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an awk script like this:

**script.awk**

```
    { k = sprintf("%s %s",$1, $2)
      s_4[ k ] += $4
      s_5[ k ] += $5
      s_6[ k ] += $6
      cnt[ k ] ++
    }

END {
      for( k in cnt ) {
          n = cnt[ k ]
          printf("%s%s%f%s%f%s%f\n", 
                  k, OFS,
                  s_4[ k ] / n, OFS, 
                  s_5[ k ] / n, OFS, 
                  s_6[ k ] / n )
      }
    }
```

You execute it with this command ling : `awk -f script.awk yourfile` .

The script aggregates the sums of fields `$4, ... , $6` into three different arrays `s_4, ... , s_6` indexed by key `k` made of `$1` and `$2`.

In the `END` the mean is calculated with the count in `cnt` and the three sums per key.

You might have to adopt the script a bit: in your example input the number of columns is not equal per line and you did not specify what to do with column `$3` ( I skipped it).

Comment: Hi @Lars Fischer ! I forgot to modify the expected output file (I've edited it now).

Comment: Also, I have 5 columns before the actual columns where the calculation starts (i.e. $5, $6, and $7). I have adjusted the arrays accordingly.

I would like to print the $3 ... $5 as well so I added

`zzz = sprintf("%s %s %s", $3, $4, $5)`

and something inside the END. It worked, but I don't know if it was technically correct. How do I exclude entries with less than 10 duplicates?